# Loading some part of view from the different controller - AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

**Problem**

I have Controller A, View A and Controller B,  View B -

Now I want to load some information from Controller A to View B.

How would I achieve this with AngularJS?

So far I have tried something like this

`<div ng-controller="controllerA"> </div>`

In my view B but nothing is getting displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a perfect example of when an angular factory could come in handy.

```
angular.module('yourModuleName')
  .factory('yourFactoryName', function() {

     var info = "";

     return {
         getInfo: function() {
              return info;
          },
         setInfo: function(data) {
              info = data;
          }
     }
}
```

And then in your controllers you would have some code that looked like this:

```
angular.module('yourModuleName')
   .controller('yourControllerName', function($scope, yourFactoryName){

       //Makes the factory value available for the controller to use in the view
       $scope.holdFactoryValue = yourFacoryName.getInfo();

       //In another controller, you could have a function like this declared to change the data
       $scope.setFactoryValue = function(data) {
          yourFactoryName.setInfo(data);
       }
   })
```